# How to stop NIntegrate from throwing slwcon error on integrals with Heaviside theta/step functions?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

The following code throws two errors (slwcon and eincr):

`NIntegrate[y x^2 HeavisideTheta[5 - x - y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]`.

Is there are "good" way to evaluate this integral **apart from removing the `HeavisideTheta` function from the integrand and converting it to explicit cutoff limits of integration?**

In my real-life much-more-complicated problem, I have already done the "convert theta function to cutoff limits of integration" method, which is fast and does not throw errors. But my goal now is to use the above "brute force" method to check my results; my confidence in this check is not very high with all these warning messages, and additionally, the results it gives are not very precise (in my messier real-life case), even when I manually adjust precision/accuracy settings.

Comment: Try using UnitStep instead of HeavisideTheta.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yup, that did the trick! Out of curiosity, any idea why this works better?

Comment: HeavisideTheta[0] returns unevaluated, while UnitStep[0] returns 1. The unevaluated code makes NIntegrate think that bad things are happening. Basically, use HeavisideTheta when using Integrate, but use UnitStep when using NIntegrate.

Comment: Or `NIntegrate[y x^2 Boole[5 - x - y > 0], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is `NIntegrate` does not recognize the singularities of `HeavysideTheta`.  At least, if you specify it, you get rid of the problem.

```
NIntegrate[y x^2 HeavisideTheta[5 - x - y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 Exclusions -> 5 - x - y == 0, AccuracyGoal -> 16]

(*  52.0833  *)
```

The default setting for `AccuracyGoal` is `Infinity`, which means `NIntegrate` will complain if the integrand is zero throughout an integration region.  The exclusion divides the integration region in two, on one of which the integrand is zero.  To get rid of the warning it will emit, set a finite `AccuracyGoal`.  I would be confident with a setting `AccuracyGoal -> a` such that `10^-a` divided by the value of the integral was less than `10^-16`.

Comment: Just by comparison, both the `UnitStep` suggestion of @CarlWoll and the `Boole` suggestion of @BobHanlon are handled automatically by `NIntegrate`.  They may be better options.  OTOH, how hard would it be to preprocess `HeavisideTheta` as part of `NIntegrate`'s symbolic preprocessing?  I'd recommend the OP suggest it to WRI.